# MySQL connector fails after switching from Python 2.7.X to 3.X

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I installed the following mysql connector via pip:

`pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python`

In my code I simply do a `import mysql.connector as Connector` and everything works fine. However, I used to use Python 2.7.X and now want to switch to Python 3.X (currently 3.5).

When I run my stuff under 2.7.X everything works fine. However, starting the same script with python 3.5 I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SWCrawler3.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Configuration as cfg
  File "/Users/Tom/SW/SWCrawler/SWCrawler/Configuration.py", line 4, in <module>
    from database.MySQLConnection import MySQLConnection as MySQLConn
  File "/Users/Tom/SW/SWCrawler/SWCrawler/database/MySQLConnection.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector as Connector
  File "../mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
  File "../mysql/connector/connection.py", line 128
    except Exception, err:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please note, that I wrote a wrapper file that I call `MySQLConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to intall the python3 packages of `mysql-connector-python`.

On my Mac I did the following:

1. brew install python3
2. pip3 install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python

After that is worked. So use `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows` with `Python 3.5`, I did something very close to toom's answer, that is :

```
pip3.5 install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```